# Is parallelism required inside "as construction" or not?

Tags: grammar

Is parallelism required inside "as construction" or not?

> He told him to stop worrying as he kept falling over throughout the
> whole duration of the 5 hours race.

The first part happens near the end and only once, and the second part happens many time throughout a very long period of time. Do you need parallelism when using the word "as"? In my understanding "as" can only be used when the two time periods are of the same length and happen at the same time.

Comment: **five-hour race** not **5 hours race**.

Comment: I agree that  "as" doesn't connect those two events properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that  "as" doesn't connect those two clauses correctly.
Actually, it's an event and a series of events (kept falling), as much as disparate time periods.